# Android what is the optimal storage mechanism for large relational text data

Tags: android, storage

In my project I have to manage large quantity of static text data(ie no modification, deletion or addition of data, only for displaying and it is based users need). To implement this I have two solutions.

1. Saving entire text data in to database, to do this I have to keep an xml file that containing text data into `asset` folder, and during the `onCreate` of database I have to fetch each text data from file and insert into database.
2. Saving text data into several xml file in `asset`, and keep the xml file name into database.

In both case I have to keep database because I want to store some flag element for each text data according to users needs. My question is which is the best method from above? or Is there any other best method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a read only database using Sqlite browser and put in assert folder and when your application execute for the first time the entire database will be copied from assert folder to the Android root database folder .

Here is link to do this ..

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I tried this because it is easy to create a database and insertion of data  using SQLite browser than creating XML file and inserting data int to specified tag without mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think **the second option is preferable and better**, because in First you have to store all xml files in asset or any other directory then you copy the whole data of those xml files into database (Time consuming) and fill the database with that xml data. (Large size of database probably searching and getting data also time consuming) .

And in your second option you have to just store file name in database. (So no worry of large size database file and you only open that file which is needed so data fetching also easily. your application size is also less)

Comment: I think you are right, copying whole data from xml to database is time consuming. I tried Sujit's answer because it is more comfortable for me. And I am up voting this answer.